# Aguardar Thread Finalizar para continuar o código - Delphi

Tags: delphi, thread

Preciso aguardar o select e o preenchimento da lista finalizar na Thread para o Result da function receber a lista carregada no metodo assincrono, é possível?
Segue o código da function:

```
function PreencheCampos(const uniQuery: TuniQuery) : TList<iEstoqueLote>;
var
  lista : TList<iEstoqueLote>;
begin
  try
    Application.CreateForm(TFrmLoading, FrmLoading);
    FrmLoading.Show;

    lista := TList<iEstoqueLote>.Create;

    ThreadSql := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
    begin
      uniQuery.Open;

      if not uniQuery.IsEmpty then
        begin
          while not uniQuery.Eof do
            begin
              aEstoqueLote := TEstoqueLote.Create;
              lista.Add(aEstoqueLote);

              if UniQuery.FindField('idestoquelote') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].idestoquelote := UniQuery.FieldByName('idestoquelote').AsInteger;

              if UniQuery.FindField('idestoque') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].idestoque := UniQuery.FieldByName('idestoque').AsInteger;

              if UniQuery.FindField('idproduto') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].idproduto := UniQuery.FieldByName('idproduto').AsInteger;

              if UniQuery.FindField('idwmsmovimentoitem') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].idwmsmovimentoitem := UniQuery.FieldByName('idwmsmovimentoitem').AsInteger;

              if UniQuery.FindField('idwmsunidadearmazenagem') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].idwmsunidadearmazenagem := UniQuery.FieldByName('idwmsunidadearmazenagem').AsInteger;

              if UniQuery.FindField('ddatavalidade') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].ddatavalidade := UniQuery.FieldByName('ddatavalidade').AsDateTime;

              if UniQuery.FindField('ddatafabricacao') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].ddatafabricacao := UniQuery.FieldByName('ddatafabricacao').AsDateTime;

              if UniQuery.FindField('nquantidade') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].nquantidade := UniQuery.FieldByName('nquantidade').AsExtended;

              if UniQuery.FindField('npesoliquido') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].npesoliquido := UniQuery.FieldByName('npesoliquido').AsExtended;

              if UniQuery.FindField('npesobruto') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].npesobruto := UniQuery.FieldByName('npesobruto').AsExtended;

              if UniQuery.FindField('nvolume') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].nvolume := UniQuery.FieldByName('nvolume').AsExtended;

              if UniQuery.FindField('ssituacao') <> nil then
                lista.Items[lista.Count - 1].ssituacao := UniQuery.FieldByName('ssituacao').AsString;

              uniQuery.Next;
            end;
        end;

      ThreadSql.Synchronize(nil, procedure
      begin
        FrmLoading.Release;
        FreeAndNil(FrmLoading);
      end);
    end);

    ThreadSql.Start;

    Result := lista;

  except on e: exception do
    begin
      TFrmTipoAviso.Mensagem('Tabela EstoqueLote : '+MensagemErroBanco(E.Message),'E',[mb_OK]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: O que acha de utilizar mutex ou semaforo?

Comment: @LeonardoGetulio, são componentes de terceiros para o Delphi?

Comment: Não, não. São todos built-in. Vou te mandar uns links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se cria `ThreadSql` do tipo `CreateAnonymousThread` e da um start, elas vão ser executadas imediatamente, porém, o `Result` será acionado imediatamente também, ou seja, o cursor vai rolar sem esperar a `ThreadSql` terminar.

Para isto, tente algo como:

```
ThreadSql.Start;
...
while not ThreadSql.Finished do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Ou seja, enquanto ela esta ocupada, fique por ali mesmo esperando.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo códigos de mutex e semáforos.

O **Mutex** cria uma trava único em memória que pode ser validado até mesmo por outros aplicativos não-delphi. Algumas vantagens são simples implementação e verificação até mesmo por outro aplicativo, e tem a desvantagem de permitir apenas 1 executor por vez.

O **Semáforo MREW** por sua vez faz validação de permissão através de objeto/variável local ou global. As vantagens de usar MREW é que você pode ter inúmeras threads executando operações de leitura sem lock no destino, o lock só acontece quando uma thread abre com permissão de escrita, é tipo o gerenciador de banco de dados, quando um tá escrevendo ninguém mais pode acessar até que ele termine, quando o escritor libera o restante pode acessar simultaneamente. A maior desvantagem é a implementação "um pouco" (quase nada) onerosa.

Link e exemplo **mutex**: http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/7251/mutex---nao-deixar-que-sua-aplicacao-seja-executada-mais-do-que-uma-vez.-

```
program Cobrancas;

uses
Forms,
Controls,
Windows,

{$R *.res}

var
hMutex: THandle;

begin
hMutex := CreateMutex(nil, true, PChar('[{23B1EEFF-4775-4FA9-9C5-6BFEAC48F551}]'));
if (hMutex <> 0) and (GetLastError = 0) then
begin
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TfrmPrincipal, frmPrincipal);
Application.Run;
end
else
MensagemDeAvisoH('Já Existe Uma Instância do Aplicativo Rodando...');
end.
```

Exemplo **semaforo MREW** (multi-read exclusive-write synchronizer):

```
//variável global
var
    SemaforoMREW: TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;

//inicializador
begin
    SemaforoMREW := TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.Create;
end;


//thread para leitura
begin
    SemaforoMREW.BeginRead;
    try
        //... operações de leitura
    finally
        SemaforoMREW.EndRead;
    end;
end;

//thread para escrita
begin
    SemaforoMREW.BeginWrite;
    try
        //... operações de escrita
    finally
        SemaforoMREW.EndWrite;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Também podia chamar um método para tratar do fim do carregamento ali antes do form.release, dentro da zona do syncronize. Acabava for ser um callback a notificar o fim da thread e até é mais performant porque nao eram necessários loops à espera que a thread terminasse